# How to map dynamic JSON to object?

Tags: json, swift, mapping

How do you create objects when beforehand you don't know all it's properties?

I want to create a framework which works with 2 files:

1. Input JSON file: Your JSON objects in a JSON file.
2. Mapping JSON file: The mapping for these JSON objects in a JSON file.

Let's say you receive the following **input** JSON `Person`:

```
{
    "name": "John Snow",
    "age": 18,
    "country_code": "UK"
}
```

And you receive another dynamic JSON **mapping** file which specifies how some properties should be mapped from the `Persons` JSON:

```
{
    "source_type": "country_code",
    "source_value": "UK",
    "destination_type": "country",
    "destination_value": "United Kingdom"
}
```

In this case I want to change the key "country_code" to "country" with the correct value. The Persons JSON has to be changed to:

```
{
    "name": "John Snow",
    "age": 18,
    "country": "United Kingdom",
}
```

I can't create a struct which conforms to Codable because the keys of the JSON can be changed from the mapping:

```
// This won't work.
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String // can be deleted
    var age: Int // can be changed to dateOfBirth
    var country: String // can be changed to country_code or national_code
}
```

It's also possible that the mapping asks to combine certain keys to create new properties:

```
{
    "source_type": "name|age",
    "source_value": "John Snow|18",
    "destination_type": "nameAge",
    "destination_value": "John Snow is 18 years old."
}
```

This would result in the following JSON object:

```
{
    "name": "John Snow",
    "age": 18,
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "nameAge": "John Snow is 18 years old."
}
```

As you can see the input JSON can be totally altered by the mapping. This means that you can't predefine your models.

How do you solve this problem in a generic way? I am not asking for the code but I'm curious about the theoretical solution on how to solve this. Currently I create wrappers around dictionaries but this is nearly the same as creating predefined models which take away the whole concept of the generic framework.

Perhaps I have to define some protocol/interface instead of actual implementations? Or work with Generics?

Comment: How will you use this dynamic models in your app?

Comment: @AntonBelousov I have no idea. I thought that perhaps a protocol could help me out by defining helper functions combined with a generic object. I doubt that this framework is technically possible.

Comment: With such a dynamic JSON, you shouldn't be using `Codable`. The whole point of `Codable` is to provide safe parsing by static typing, but if your JSON is dynamic to such extent, you won't be able to provide all properties/types at compile time, so you won't be able to use `Codable`. However, if you don't even know the possible property names and types that your JSON can have at compile time, you shouldn't even use a concrete type, you should simply store the values in a `Dictionary` which fits the dynamic nature of your JSON.

Comment: @DávidPásztor That's a very nice and clear explanation and I fully agree with that approach although it would become a headache retrieving values from a generic dictionary. I guess this dictionary approach would also be the solution when the expected JSON object is always the same (Person) but with dynamic properties which are based on the mapping file?

Comment: As long as you are aware of all possible values and their types, you can use an actual type, you just have to create optional properties (for instance if a `Person` can have a date of birth, which is a `Date` or an age which is an `Int`, you can do `var dob:Date?` and `var age:Int?`), but if the properties and their types can change without your knowledge, then you'll have to use a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Sounds good. I'll use dictionaries because the properties are fully dynamic even on an expected type like Person. The best solution would be to create a wrapper around this dictionary with some helper functions for some basic operations. I wonder if it's possible to create an actual type like Person though where 90% of the properties are always static and put the remaining 10% of dynamic properties in a dictionary property of Person so you have 90% of the  properties always exposed and the remaining through that dictionary .. although this seems dirty.

Comment: Sure, if most of the properties are static, it makes more sense to create an actual type containing all known properties as instance properties of a concrete type and store all dynamic properties in a `Dictionary`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for your help - I now have some ideas on what's possible and what's not. Can you summarise your replies in a comment so I can mark it as accepted?